# Why am I getting this AttributeError?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm in the process of changing my KML library from python 2 to 3, and I've hit a snag here. Whenever the KML object is created, with `k = KML()` for example, I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'KML' object has no attribute 'doc'` with reference to the last line of the given code. I can't tell what's going on here, as I've clearly defined the attribute. Here's the code.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class KML(ET.Element):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("kml")
        self.doc = ET.Element("Doc")
        super().append(self.doc)     #error points here
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the whole error message with the entire stack trace.

Comment: why are you calling `super()` twice? did you mean to do `self.append(...)`?

Comment: @BrenBarn You can just run this in the interpreter and it'll kick back an Attribute Error with no real stack trace. In my longer code the `k = KML()` is called from another file, but I don't think that's relevant.

@shx2 I define another `append` later on in the code, and I want to run `ET.Element`'s append not `KML`'s.

Comment: The problem here is that you're using the C implementation of `ElementTree` (because in 3.2+ that automatically happens as long as the C implementation can be imported), which doesn't allow you to attach extra attributes this way. If you try the `k.doc = 'Doc'` anywhere but an `__init__` or `__new__` method, you'll get an `AttributeError` on _that_ line. Inside an `__init__` or `__new__`, it will not raise, but will do nothing, so the first attempt to access `self.doc` will raise.

Comment: Anyway, the question is what you're trying to accomplish by attaching members to an `Element`. There might be a better way to do the same thing at a higher level, or you might need to override `__new__`, or you might just want to switch to lxml's etree implementation.

Comment: Also, the `append`, and the fact that the value is an `Element`, are both irrelevant, so you may wan to simplify your `__init__` to just super-init, then `self.doc = "Doc"`, then `print(self.doc)`. That will avoid red herrings like the first few comments (which nobody could have known were red herrings without checking).

Comment: Thanks @abarnert, I'll switch implementations.

Answer (score 3):

The root problem here is that `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element` isn't designed to be subclassed.

I don't think this was intentional, they just didn't expect anyone to subclass it, and didn't think about it either way. In Python 3, almost anything you write in pure Python ends up nicely subclassable, but a C-API class is a different story. And if you look at [`xml.etree.ElementTree.Element`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#l1708), it's actually `_elementtree.Element`, which is [implemented in C](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Modules/_elementtree.c) (as a trivial port of `cElementTree` from 2.x).

Let's take a stripped-down implementation to see the problem:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class KML(ET.Element):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__('kml')

k = KML()
k.doc = 'Doc'
```

This will raise an `AttributeError` as soon as you try to assign to `k.doc`. Why? Well, that calls `__setattr__`, which neither you nor `ET.Element` have implemented, and the default implementation for builtins won't work because you neither you nor `ET.Element` have set yourself up as a mutable builtin class, so it will raise an `AttributeError`. Exactly the same as if you tried this with an `ET.Element` instead of a subclass, or with an `int`.

But:

```
class KML(ET.Element):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__('kml')
        self.doc = 'Doc'

k = KML()
```

Now there's no exception… but it also doesn't set the attribute, as you can see by trying to access `self.doc` right after setting it, or `k.doc` right after creating it. That's because the attribute-creation exception gets swallowed when it's inside a `__new__` or `__init__`, which makes the problem harder to debug.

So, what do you do about it?

---

One possibility is to implement `__setattr__` yourself.

This won't be true for all non-subclassing-friendly C-API classes, but in this case, you actually have a proper `__dict__` that the default (`object`) implementation of `__setattr__` and friends use, you just don't have that implementation.

You could monkeypatch it in, or try to set up the proper multiple inheritance (but `Element` is going to have problems with that for similar reasons as your original problem).

But I think it's much simpler to just write it explicitly:

```
def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
    self.__dict__[attr] = value
def __delattr__(self, attr):
    del self.__dict__[attr]
```

---

Another possibility is to force the pure-Python implementation by preventing the C implementation from replacing it. Although this seems like a bad hack, it will work:

```
import _elementtree
del _elementtree.Element
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

---

Finally, you can use the `lxml` implementation of the `ElementTree` API, which has a number of other advantages over the stdlib one. Of course it also has some disadvantages, the chief one being that you need to manually install it (and it depends on the C library `libxml2`, which you also may need to install).